# Chart data of object gets overwritten, but only the first object that is interacted with is affected

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, vuex

Here is this a code sand box proving and showcasing this issue: https://codesandbox.io/embed/ql4rm9734w?fontsize=14

When a user clicks on a button in the app's. A widget is meant to show the data of that object. The the object contains an array that is used to produce a graph. The first object's button click seems to display and function correctly. So does the second and the third. But when the first objects button is clicked again the chart data property of the object is overwritten with the chart data of the previously clicked object.

The application has been built in Vue.Js, with Highcharts, and Highcharts official Vue wrapper rendering the charts. The data is stored in a Vuex store.

The page gets populated with a button for each object. When a objects button is clicked a custom event is fired containing the object data. The object click event handler mutates the store passing the object to the store to be saved as a active marker object. The object Widget that displays the data to the user gets its data from the stores active marker object.

this process works fine for every other object that uses this system. It also only ever effects the first object clicked, all subsequent objects are unaffected and work correctly.

I have tried the following with no luck

- Vue dev tools and debugging, shows the symptoms of the error but does not point to where the error takes place.
- I have tried making the data property a pseudo private property that can only be accessed with setters and getters. The setter is never called.
- Added second property in the class to act as a not modified storage variable for the original data given at construction time. This second property also gets modified.
- When examining the store in depth, it looked like the object array in the store was not affected by the bug. However when refactored to use the object from the store directly the bug is still there.
- I tried to separate out the data into a separate state property that is not related to the object in any direct way... still the same bug.
- I also tried with a every small data array (15 elements) still the bug persisted.
- I have even built a mini replica project in the hopes that at the smallest scale the bug does not appear and hopefully it would be a silly typo or something... but again, even this mini version of my app still shows the bug. the Mini version can be found here: https://github.com/ChadRoberts21/ChartMapBug
- Built a more refined smaller example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/ql4rm9734w?fontsize=14

The code is available from https://codesandbox.io/embed/ql4rm9734w?fontsize=14

I expect that the correct chart data is always shown in the object widget and for the object to not have its data property overridden at all unless I expressly choose to do so in a Vuex mutation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs, because of fact that the Highcharts mutates the data, which not exactly complies the Vue conceptions. Generally, if you are able to avoid the data mutation you shouldn't do that at all. I've just answered that question directly on the `highcharts-vue` repository, so there you can find more specific description about why the issue occurs.

In essence (for another users searching for the answer on that question), the best way out of the problem will be to apply a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) when assigning a new data to series:

*FooWidget.vue (**chartOptions()** computed property part)*

```
series: [{
    showInLegend: false,
    type: "column",
    color: this.foo.colour,
    data: [...this.foo.data],
    pointInterval: this.foo.interval,
    pointStart: this.foo.startPoint,
    gapSize: 4,
    tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
    },
    fillColor: {
        linearGradient: {
            x1: 0,
            y1: 0,
            x2: 0,
            y2: 1
        }
     },
     threshold: null
 }]
```

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/w2wyx88vxl

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are using computed for fetching data. when you pass data in click event it's actually updated foos array of the store(reference of state.foos). so when you click on test2 the data in the store of foos array is updated.

Try to console log foos array in store setActiveFoo method you can see that foos array is updated with other values.

```
setActiveFoo(state, payload) {
      console.log("In store foos")
      console.log(state.foos);
      state.activeFoo = payload;
    }
```

Try this code. I think you need to send the copy of foos array in computed it will solve the problem.

```
computed: {
    foos() {
      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters.foos));
    },
    activeFoo() {
      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters.activeFoo));
    }
  }
```

Comment: This should not work, but it does. I still believe that there is a much deeper problem. Why are the other properties of the object not effected by the same issue? In my production application I have a huge complex nested object what works perfectly except the singular property that highcharts uses. Thank you for your answer by I really appreciate it!

Comment: other properties of the object are not affecting bcz you are not using it in dispatch and in other methods also.you are just using foo array of state so it's only affecting foos array.The problem is that if you change the value from the return getters and try to change the value then it will also update the state variable.